# Print file output row wise in new CSV file using Shell Script

Tags: shell, csv, text, string-formatting

I have file:

```
           cat abc.txt
            Data is here
           ASDF 1234
           GHJKL 5678
           !@#$% 0011
```

I am using command "(echo "Random data is:,"; cat abc.txt) | xargs  > red1.csv"

I need to print in data in below format 
**

```
Random data is:  Data is here 
                 ASDF 1234 
                 GHJKL 5678 
                 !@#$% 0011
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and make it more comprehensible

Comment: Can you check now if this works ?

Comment: Thanks alot it works exactly the same way it has to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used printf statement to play around with formatting and placement of strings. of course you need to modify it as per your requirement. you would have to play around value of variables v and j as per your requirement. Awk statement was used inside echo statement using command substitution.

```
 echo "Random data is : $(awk -v f="%35s\n" -v j="%20s\n" 'NR>1{printf f,$0} NR==1 {printf j,$0}' abc.txt) "
Random data is :         Data is here
                          ASDF 1234
                         GHJKL 5678
                         !@#$% 0011
```